# Why do I get a server timeout calling an API via HttpClient but Postman is fine?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to make a `GET` request to a RESTful service but the .NET `HttpClient` is receiving a timeout, but via Postman this returns an expected response (an error response, since I'm not yet "logged in") within seconds.

## What I've tried:

1. I have checked the URLs are the same and they are.
2. I thought perhaps Postman's automagical headers are the issue, but after setting these in the `HttpClient` I still receive a timeout.
3. If I increase the timeout on the `HttpClient` I still get a timeout from the server (`(504) Gateway Timeout`).

```cs
Client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip
});
var objTask = Client.GetStringAsync(objUrl);
objTask.Wait();
strResponse = objTask.Result;
strResponse = Client.GetStringAsync(objUrl).Result;
```

Why am I receiving a timeout via HttpClient?

## Note:

Our WebApi is calling our WCF Service, which in turn is calling the 3rd party RESTful service via HttpClient---for security reasons I can't call the 3rd party API directly from our WebApi controller. The website is based on the .NET 4.0 Framework.

Comment: Does your computer have a proxy that Postman ignores? Also try looking at the agent string.

Comment: @gunr2171 It does indeed have a proxy, I wasn't aware Postman would ignore it. I'll check this now.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the issue. In the settings I have `Use System Proxy` enabled

Comment: Another debugging tip is to use a network traffic monitor like Fiddler to inspect the http request/response. You can compare the response from Postman and your code to see the differences.

Comment: @gunr2171 That's a good tip. Thank you

Comment: @gunr2171 I can see the request to the WebApi but not the request to the other service. The WebApi calls the other service through a self-hosted WCF Service. Our website can't communicate with the rest of the world, except via our WCF service through a single port. I've realised I've not tested it since the call was made via the WCF service.

Comment: Disable proxy.  You probably do not have a proxy and the HttpClient with proxy enable will try to connect to the proxy and timeout.

Comment: @jdweng I disabled the proxy via Internet Explorer, but this doesn't seem to have fixed it either

Comment: You need to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first postman request with the fir c# request.  The default headers are different in Postman and Net Library.

Comment: you do realize you're making, then awaiting response for two identical requests sequentially, right? I would also try removing the `HttpClientHandler()` instantiation

Comment: Try following :            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
            myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URI");
            request.Proxy = myProxy;

Comment: @jdweng Fiddler doesn't seem to be picking up the request made via the Self-hosted WCF service, even though it's hosted on "localhost". I'll have to update where this is hosted on dev.

Comment: @JoshE Yeah, I'm aware of the two identical requests. My code was initially the latter request but wasn't sure if it was something to do with the tasks.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. That didn't give a timeout error, so I need to figure out why disabling the proxy on IE wasn't working, or if there's something else I can do.

Comment: Are you seeing any TCP messages?  The TLS will use TCP for the verification.  Does Fiddler show the request using Postman?

Comment: So is code working?

Comment: Bypassing the proxy on `HttpWebRequest` is working, but I need the Decompression as well. I'm going to have another look tomorrow at this tomorrow, it's been a long day.

Comment: By decompression are you referring to the GZIP?

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I'm referring to the GZIP

Comment: You probably have seen code like this : HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
hwr.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

Comment: @jdweng With your help I've realised the proxy settings are saved within the app.config of the self-hosted WCF services. I'm going to dig deeper into this. Would you or like to provide an answer stating this? I can then accept it.

Comment: The `HttpClientHandler` has a `Proxy` property, which I can use to bypass local proxy settings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lots of help from @jdweng and @gunr2171, I've realised the issue was due to the proxy stored in the `App.Config` on the self-hosted WCF Services. If I commented this out, I wouldn't get a time-out issue.

The `HttpClient` constructor can take in a `HttpClientHandler`, which has a `Proxy` property where you can bypass the local proxy as so:

```cs
return new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip,
    Proxy = new WebProxy()
    {
        BypassProxyOnLocal = true
    }
})
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https:\\my.service")
};
```